# "I am keeping a pet hamster." vs "I keep a pet hamster" Difference?

Tags: difference, sentence-structure, present-tense, present-continuous

This sentence:

> I am keeping a pet hamster.

And this sentence:

> I keep a pet hamster

Sounds exactly the same to me, any minute difference, if any at all? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. We would use _I keep_ when the hamster is a permanent member of your household, and the continuous tense for an ongoing but temporary situation - "I am looking after my friend's hamster while he is away".

Comment: I would not use keeping here to mean look after or taking care of. It sounds like a foreigner speaking English.

Comment: @Lambie: [***You don't keep a dog and bark yourself.***](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Sayings/XYZ/You_don_t_keep_a_dog_and_bark_yourself_525.php#:~:text=Possible%20meaning%3A,to%20do%20the%20job%20yourself.) I doubt I've ever heard a native speaker say *You don't **have** a dog and bark yourself.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have no idea what you are on about....My comment was clear.

Comment: @Lambie: Your comment includes both an infinitive and an -ing form *(to mean **look** after or **taking** care of)*, so it would be perfectly natural for people to interpret *I would not use keeping* as implying a restriction on *all* forms of the verb ***to keep***. But I expect you knew that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wrote: I would not use "keeping" **here**" i.e. in this context. And non-English speakers don't do backbends to interpret things....

Comment: @Lambie:  And you a native speaker! Stereotypically, most native speakers don't metaphorically ***do backbends*** - but they certainly might ***bend over backwards*** to oblige someone!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now you're telling me how to express myself?? I chose to say do backbends, **a backbend goes further than bend over backwards**. But I guess you are not gymnast. And don't appreciate creativity. In a backbend, your hands touch the floor behind you. In bend over backwards they do not.

Answer (score 3):

> 1: *I keep a pet hamster*

...is slightly "unusual" phrasing (compared to *I **have** a pet hamster*), so if it came from a "careful" native speaker it would probably carry some "context-specific" nuance over and above the bare literal sense. Perhaps the speaker is implying *...for the benefit of my mental health*<sup>1</sup> or something.

2: *I am keeping a pet hamster*

...is *very* unusual phrasing. The main thing implied by Present Continuous here is *this is a **current** activity* (that doesn't necessarily extend far into the past or future). Perhaps the speaker is *temporarily looking after* a friend's hamster.

---

Note that although Simple Present *I **have** a pet* is the idiomatic standard here, the ***keep*** version is "okay-ish". And we can easily imagine contexts where Present Continuous *I **am keeping** a pet hamster* (temporarily, for my friend) is "acceptable", but there's really no credible context where a native speaker would say *I am having a pet hamster*. That's an "Indian English" [shiboleth](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shibboleth) which should always be avoided.

---

<sup>1</sup> This suggested "reason for using ***keep*** rather than ***have*** illustrates the more general point. We tend to ***keep*** "working/food animals" (security dogs, farm cats, chickens, pigs), whereas we ***have*** animals primarily treated as pets/companions.

Comment: Great - thanks!

Comment: I think saying "keep" instead of "have" regarding pets specifically (it _would_ definitely be weird for inanimate objects) is a fairly common substitution in English, so wouldn't always be seen as unusual. It might be prevalent in some dialects more than others.

Comment: @Crazymoomin: I'm quite certain the preference for either ***have*** or ***keep*** (pet or "working" animal) would vary according to specific circumstances. For example, you're more likely to ***keep a dog*** for security purposes, and ***have a cat*** for companionship and "strokeability". But I'd bet any money that on average farmers are more likely to ***keep a cat*** for vermin control. I kinda doubt that "dialectal variation" would be significant here, compared to the extent to which the choice is affected by how much the owner perceives the pet as a "working" animal KEPT FOR A PURPOSE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure it's that clear cut. For small animals I'd say "keep" is more common, especially when there's more than one. So someone _keeps_ chickens or rats, even if they're just pets. Keeping a dog or a cat does seem to be a rarer phrase.

Comment: @Crazymoomin: We must agree to differ. Sure, there will always be some people who don't adhere to the same usage rules as others - probably not as members geographical or socioeconomic "dialect group" in this case, but I dunno. But so far as I'm concerned, someone primarily *keeps chickens* for their eggs, whereas their children might *have* rats as pets.

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kept+a+dog%2Chad+a+dog&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckept%20a%20dog%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20a%20dog%3B%2Cc0) showing how rare ***kept a dog*** is compared to ***had a dog*** (at least a 20-to-1 difference). And compare it to [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kept+a+guard+dog%2Chad+a+guard+dog&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3), showing that *had a **guard** dog* is only about twice as common as ***kept** a guard dog* for the "working" animal.

Comment: @FumbleFingers We'll end up in the weeds around the often fuzzy distinction between pets, livestock and working animals in many instances. Regardless, I wouldn't go so far to say it's _unusual_ to use "keep" instead of "have" especially for animals that aren't dogs and cats, even if they are just pets. Perhaps not as common, but it wouldn't seem an odd turn of phrase.

Comment: @Crazymoomin: Well, I only *just* "went so far to say it's unusual"! After all, I did qualify it as only ***slightly*** unusual, AND I put "unusual" in scare quotes to imply "less unusual than is usually implied by the use of this word"! :) And whilst it may be that there are many native speakers who would naturally use ***keep*** where I would use ***have***, I will continue to assume such people are outnumbered by those who have the same default preference as me - so if they ***do*** decide to choose the "less favoured" term in any given context, I'll assume there's some "nuance" as stated.